# React - Add and Delete in the same component results in "layout thrashing"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am using a code (written by other developer) which uses `setState` in `componentDidMount` I know it's wrong.

This code uses a component for both `Create` and `Edit`. 
In `componentDidMount` it checks if there is an ID in the Props. if it has, it means it should be `Edited`. If there is no ID, it means a new record should be `Created`.

By having an ID, it will call an API to fetch a record. After getting the result, it use `setState` to set each value in the `state`.

This code cause some layout thrashing because it will trigger a second `render()`

I want to know what is the best way to have a form with the values (from database) and then edit them. without using the `setState` in `componentDidMount`

Regards.

Comment: Who say's it is wrong to set your state in componentDidMount, it is perfectly okay.

Comment: It is wrong. Updating the state after a component mount will trigger a second render() call and can lead to property/layout thrashing

Comment: It's not wrong according to their docs https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Comment: The Doc didn't say it is not wrong. It's wrong according to https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-did-mount-set-state.md

Comment: Adel, it's not "wrong" just because it is in a ruleset for some linter. It does trigger a re-render, which can be desirable or undesirable depending on the specific circumstances, but it's not an objectively bad thing to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wrap your component in a container. You can read a nice writeup on it [here](https://medium.com/@learnreact/container-components-c0e67432e005).

Basically, your component that you have now will become stateless. Then you make a component that is stateful, and acts as a wrapper for your current component. That stateful component fetches the necessary data and then passes it to your view component as a props. You can have all the same functions, data, etc just pass them in as props. This way you can set state before your view component renders (maybe use componentWillMount, or even set everything up in your constructor if the design allows)

```
class ExampleComponentContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            stateStuff: 'blahblah',
            boolean: false
        }
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        let data = myApiUtilsFetch();
        this.setState(() => {
            return {
                stateStuff: 'new data',
                boolean: true 
            }
        }) 
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <ExampleComponent passProps={props} />
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing an id to the next component isn't wrong. Also setting state on componentDidMount its ok. The concept here generally seems correct.

The best way from my opinion is to use redux to have all the user's info from a call to a state and handling the state for edit or saving. Another great tool for this is redux-form that you can use.

Basically you pass from the ajax call the user info to a state. Then from state to the values of the inputs. Then any change on button press send it back on the server.

This can be done with either component state or redux but the concept either way is correct.